# How do I iterate over array result from findBy Doctrine query in Twig template

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

I have this code in my controller:

```
$entProductosSolicitud = $em->getRepository("AppBundle:ProductoSolicitud")->findBy(array(
    'solicitud_usuario' => $entSolicitudUsuario->getId()
));
```

And I pass it to the view as:

'entProductosSolicitud' => $entProductosSolicitud

That will produce an output as the one below:

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => ProductoSolicitud {#6303 ▼
    #producto: Producto {#6318 }
    #solicitud_usuario: SolicitudUsuario {#4525 }
    #condicion_producto: CondicionProducto {#6320 }
    #finalidad_producto: FinalidadProducto {#6324 }
    #lote: 11
    #procedencia_producto: ProcedenciaProducto {#6326 }
    #productoCodigosArancelarios: PersistentCollection {#6332 }
    #id: 5
  }
]
```

And that is right since I can have more than one entity so `findBy` is the right method to use for find entities. Now I need to iterate over each entity properties so I can access for example `Producto` name and ID as: `item.getProducto.getName()` and `item.getProducto.getId()` but since the var `entProductosSolicitud` have a array then I don't know how to iterate over it. I've tried this:

```
{% for key, value in entProductosSolicitud %}
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="{{ value[key].getProducto.getId }}" name="" /></td>
    <td>{{ value[key].getProducto.getNombre }}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

But that doesn't work so, how do I iterate over `entProductosSolicitud` in order to access their properties in the array result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twig and Symfony show several examples of iterating over an array of objects here:

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#templates

All you have to do is this:

```
{% for item in entProductosSolicitud %}
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="{{ item.getProducto.getId }}" name="" /></td>
        <td>{{ item.getProducto.getNombre }}</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```